# Hash breaks .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using this .htaccess to forward a text and an url to Twitter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^mytxt=(.*)&myurl=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=aprofile&text=%1&url=%2&via=myprofile [R,L]
```

It works fine as long no #hash is within the string. (With a #hash it returns just a 403 forbidden.)
This is the URL: `http://www.example.com/twitter/?mytxt=hello+world+#randomhash&myurl=http://example.com`

How to fix that?
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Try using the URL encoded value for the `#` sign.

`http://www.example.com/twitter/?mytxt=hello+world+%23randomhash&myurl=http://example.com`

Comment: I tried it but Twitter displays %23 instead of # than. Are there other possibilities? Is there a way doing it with PHP if .htaccess can't do it?